# Horizontal drift of snowflake

Tags: random-walk, classical-mechanics

I wonder if the random-walk dynamics of falling snowflakes
is understood well enough to estimate
the likely sideways drift of a single snowflake falling in a windless environment,
from its cloud creation to ground touchdown, a sort of expected life-history
of a single flake?

For definiteness, say each flake is created in a nimbostratus cloud at height 1km.
My guess: sideways drifting is on the order of 100m...?

   [image]

   <sub>([National Geographic image](http://www.artflakes.com/en/products/national-geographic-gentle-falling-snow-in-a-field-with-a-forest-backdrop))</sub>